# if $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cdot b_{n,m})=0$ what can we say about $b_{n,m}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $a$,$b \in \mathbb{R}_+$ be two real positive numbers

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a<a_n<b$

Let $\{b_{n,m}\}_{n,m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a double complex sequence such that
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty
(a_n \cdot b_{n,m})
=
0
$$
What can we say about $b_{n,m}$

Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n,m}$ convergent ?

Is the limit $\lim_{m \to \infty} b_{n,m} =0$ ?

or anything else?

Comment: What's a "double complex sequence"?

Comment: @Gono for all $n$ and $m$ in $\mathbb{N}: b_{n,m} \in \mathbb{C}$, it is a sequence with two indices

Comment: If $A$ is a vector and $B_m$ a sequence of vectors so that $\langle A,B_m\rangle\to 0$ for $m\to \infty$ then you can say nothing more than that the vectors $B_m$ are increasingly orthogonal to $A$, if they are bounded away from the zero vector.

Comment: @LutzL exuse me, so could i say that $B_m \to 0$ or becoming orthogonal?

Comment: There is nothing about convergence of the sequence $B_m$. Anything wld is possible. Note that the vectors orthogonal to $A$ form a hyperplane of co-dmension $1$. The only thing one might conclude is that the distance to that hyperplane goes to zero. Which is exactly what that formula says.

Comment: @LutzL thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a_n) = 1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,\dots$

Define the 4-vector $v=(1,-1/2,-1/4,0).$ Then consider the sequence of 4 vectors $v,(1/2)v,(1/3)v,(1/4)v,(1/5)v \dots.$ We form a sequence $(c_n)$ by stringing the coordinates of these 4-vectors together. Thus

$$(c_n)= 1,-1/2,-1/4,0,1/2,-1/4,-1/8,0,1/3,-1/6,-1/12,0,1/4,-1/8,-1/16, 0,\dots.$$

Now define $b_{nm} = c_n$ for all $n,m.$ We then have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cdot b_{nm}=0\,\,\text { for all } m.$$

The series $\sum_n b_{nm},$ summed in groups of four, gives $1/4 + 1/8+ 1/12+ 1/16 + \cdots = \infty.$ And $\lim_{m\to \infty}b_{nm} \ne 0$ unless $n$ is a multiple of $4.$

Comment: thanks for you nice example